# Save dotted field in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, mongoose

I'am trying to save the outcome from an JSON API to a MongoDB collection.
The JSON data I'am trying to save has the following structure:

```
compatibility: {
    2.7.1: {
        2.2.6: [
            100,
            1,
            1
        ]
     },
     2.8.3: {
         2.2.6: [
             100,
             2,
             2
         ]
     }
 }
```

But I'am getting the following error: The dotted field '2.7.1' in 'compatibility.2.7.1' is not valid for storage.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

You can't have `.` in field names. Dot is some how special in mongodb. For example if you insert

```
db.test.insert({
   a: {
      b: 2
   }
});
```

And then you can search that item with

```
db.test.find({
   'a.b': 2
});
```

So imagine you are able to have dot in field name and you insert

```
db.test.insert({
   a: {
      b: 2
   },
   'a.b': 3
});'
```

Then it would be strange to search by `'a.b'`, wouldn't it?