# Is a variable for a field name allowed during update in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I have been trying to update a collection i have.Problem is,i dont know the field name so am relying on some logic to come up with the field name.

For instance

```
  Er.update({ _id: "BCwrQEdiTr9GMmKWW" }, {
    $set: {
      "x" : y
    }
  });
```

where x is the field name.

This is my code

```
var obj = {};
obj[x] = y;

Er.update({ _id: "BCwrQEdiTr9GMmKWW" }, {$set: {obj}});
```

I am getting this error

> update failed: MongoError: The dotted field 'ersubjects.0.English' in
>   'obj.ersubjects.0.English' is not valid for storage.

`English` is a field under `ersubjects` so i want to update it this way `ersubjects.0.English` and it works on mongo.

Why is this not working in meteor?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't store documents that have a dot in the key. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28011278/3992613) for an explanation.

What you can do is use lodash's extremely handy [_.set](https://lodash.com/docs#set) function to create your object with dynamic keys like this:

```
var obj = {};
var variableKey = 'ersubjects';
_.set(obj, [variableKey, 0, 'English], 'someValue');
```

Now you can safely store this object to Mongo.

Comment: Complains set is not a function.

Comment: What version of lodash are you using? `_.set` is available from version 3.7.0

Comment: OMG,i just installed 0.7.1,which is a bit weird coming from what looks like their official lodash distro on atmosphere `alethes:lodash`

Comment: https://atmospherejs.com/stevezhu/lodash this is the most used package on atmosphere. As a side note, I would recommend using meteor 1.3 and move from atmosphere to npm packages asap. No more problems like this :)

Comment: I will switch to npm soon. Using lodash in helpers is proving problematic,even after installing lodash.

Comment: underscore to lodash will be a nuclear blast for my project , https://github.com/rclai/meteor-lodash-replace-underscore   as i am also using iron router